# Jquery Modal Popup not showing embedded pdf file

Tags: c#, jquery

I have this issue that I am trying to resolve with modal popup. When I call the popup from the code behind. The link does not show the embedded pdf file, just the blank embedded black screen.

However  when I take the embed tag outside of the modal popup and show it based on the response from the code behind, the pdf file shows on the screen. So I know the path is right. I have tried calling the modal popup in the code behind after the pdffile.src but no change in the response.

```
<script>
    function ShowPopup() {
    $(function () {
        $("#displaypdf").dialog({
            modal: true,
            height : 800,
            width : 800,
        });
     });
     return false;
    };
</script>

<div id="displaypdf" style="display:none">
     <embed id="pdffile" class="pdfsource" runat="server" />
</div>

protected void SelectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup();", true);
    string DirPath = Request.QueryString["Dir"];
    Button btnButton = sender as Button;
    GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)btnButton.NamingContainer;
    Label SelectLink = (Label)gvRow.FindControl("SelectLink");
    pdffile.Src = "file:Z:/testdirectory/" + DirPath + "/" + SelectLink.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I see that you want the browser to load a local resource (file:Z:...), which is not allowed in most browsers due to the security risk it exposes.

To confirm if that's the problem, try changing:

```
pdffile.Src = "file:Z:/testdirectory/" + DirPath + "/" + SelectLink.Text;
```

to

```
pdffile.Src = "http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf";
```

and see if the document loads (if not, check your browser console for any errors).

I recommend you to serve those documents from a http endpoint, like setting up a virtual folder in IIS pointing it to your local network path (e.g. Z:/testdirectory/) where the files will be located, then set `pdffile.Src` to this virtual directory file path instead.

Comment: This is for an internal website so I changed the security settings to allow pdfs to be seen. I did take your suggestion about hard coding the src as a test. I created a pdf and hard coded the path Z:/testdirectory/testfolder/testfile.pdf in the embed tag and it shows the pdf in the modal popup. So the issue is the pdffile.src string that is passing from the code behind to the embed tag.

Comment: In that case, after clicking on `SelectButton` you could "Inspect" the updated html to see how it was rendered. If you are using Chrome this is trivial, just right click on the dialog that contains your `embed` element and click "Inspect" from the contextual menu, then you should be able to see the value of the `src` attribute.

Comment: Btw, your url is not properly formatted, the file protocol should look like this `file://`, so your code should looks more like: `pdffile.Src = "file://Z:/testdirectory/" + DirPath + "/" + SelectLink.Text;`

Comment: No it is in the right format. file:// gives me an access denied error. I viewed the source of the embed file, copied the value of the src attribute and pasted it into a new broswer window and it showed the pdf.

Comment: Navigating to the url by yourself (by pasting it in the address bar) vs. accessing that url from inside the document are two different things, they have different security contexts. I'm curious, when you say _"I changed the security settings to allow pdfs to be seen"_ how did you do that? and what browser are you testing against?

Comment: I added the domain to trusted sites to view PDFs. I know that those are two different things. My concern was both paths were the same.